# Add schema name with table while creating sql*loader control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

How can i add schema name while creating sql*loader control file.

My Control File

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1) 
LOAD DATA 
APPEND 
INTO TABLE "student" 
WHEN (1:1) <> BLANKS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(student_id, first_name, last_name, dob, addr1, addr2, city, state, zip_code, created_by, created_dt )
```

Comment: you add it before your table name.

Comment: Please give me an example.

Comment: Post your current CTL File and will let you know where to add.

Comment: OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE "student"
WHEN (1:1) <> BLANKS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(student_id,
first_name,
last_name,
dob,
addr1,
addr2,
city,
state,
zip_code,
created_by,
created_dt
)

Comment: schema name is scott

Answer (score 0):

The schema name should be mentioned just before the table name.

```
APPEND INTO TABLE scott.student
```

Tables should not be quoted, that's a bad practice

Comment: i create a public synonym and then call the table in double quotes. Now it is working. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MohsinALvi Its not a good practice to create table_names with double quotes. And also, If you are not aware of this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers